# Laravel: active column that behave like softdelete

Tags: laravel, laravel-models

I have a model accounts in Laravel that uses Softdeletes.
Beside that, I want another column called active, that behaves kinda the same. If its sets to XXX  then all `Account::` calls shouldnt include them in the return. Until I set the active value to YYY, after this, they should be included.
Is there any way to do this?
I want to set the XXX and YYY values by my own. So I could say return only if active = 1 or active = whatEverIWant

Edit: I know I could do that by checking the value at every call, but I already use the accounts at a lot of places and dont want to add it everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be approached in two ways

**Option 1: Global Scope**

You can define a global scope on the model, which returns records only with active set to 1

```php
class Account extends Model
{

    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope('active', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('active', 1);
        });
    }

    // rest of the class code
}
```

Now all the queries on the model will have the constraint defined in global scope.

When you do want to retrieve records irrespective of whether active is set to 1 not, you can call it with `withoutGlobalScopes()` or `withoutGlobalScope('active')` - will remove the constraint defined in global scope.

```php
$accounts = Account::withoutGlobalScopes()->get();

//OR

$accounts = Account::withoutGlobalScope('active');
```

**Option 2: Local Scope**

You can define a local scope on the model class for each of active and inactive states

```php
class Account extends Model
{
    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        $query->where('active', 1);
    }

    public function scopeInactive($query)
    {
        $query->where('active', '<>', 1);
    }
}
```

Then when you want to filter records which are active or inactive

```php
$activeAccounts = Account::active()->get();

$inactiveAccounts = Account::inactive()->get();

$accounts = Account::get(); //to get all records irrespective of whether active or inactive
```

Laravel softdeletes also uses scopes behind the scenes.

Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: Thank you much, exactly what I searched for. But didnt aware of the scopes